# Understanding PyTorch geometric RandomLinkSplit

Tags: python, pytorch-geometric

When I try to use the [RandomLinkSplit](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.transforms.RandomLinkSplit.html) transform to split into a train and test set in a 7/8 split, I receive two objects, both of them with just 7/8 of the links in the edge_index. Where are the remaining 1/8 located?

Original HomogeneousData:

```py
HeteroData(
  voter={ num_nodes=104 },
  proposal={ num_nodes=2216 },
  (voter, votes, proposal)={ edge_index=[2, 8303] },
  (proposal, voted, voter)={ edge_index=[2, 8303] }
)
```

Data returned after calling:

```py
PyG.transforms.RandomLinkSplit(
    is_undirected=True, 
    edge_types=[g.edge_types[0]],
    rev_edge_types=[g.edge_types[1]],
    num_val=0, 
    num_test=1/8,
    add_negative_train_samples=False,
    split_labels=True,
    key='ground_truth',
)

tr = HeteroData(
  voter={ num_nodes=104 },
  proposal={ num_nodes=2216 },
  (voter, votes, proposal)={
    edge_index=[2, 7266],
    pos_ground_truth=[7266],
    pos_ground_truth_index=[2, 7266]
  },
  (proposal, voted, voter)={ edge_index=[2, 7266] }
)
val = HeteroData(
  voter={ num_nodes=104 },
  proposal={ num_nodes=2216 },
  (voter, votes, proposal)={
    edge_index=[2, 7266],
    pos_ground_truth=[0],
    pos_ground_truth_index=[2, 0]
  },
  (proposal, voted, voter)={ edge_index=[2, 7266] }
)
ts = HeteroData(
  voter={ num_nodes=104 },
  proposal={ num_nodes=2216 },
  (voter, votes, proposal)={
    edge_index=[2, 7266],
    pos_ground_truth=[1037],
    pos_ground_truth_index=[2, 1037],
    neg_ground_truth=[1037],
    neg_ground_truth_index=[2, 1037]
  },
  (proposal, voted, voter)={ edge_index=[2, 7266] }
)
```

All objects have the same edge_index, with about 7/8 of the nodes, where are the rest? It appears as if the test set is just a subset of the train set, and 1/8 of the edges disappeared. How can I obtain two (or three) graphs in which the edge index is just the disjoint subset of the original?